# How to connect sql server with Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to connect my IOS app with sql server 2008 to do a Login and register button.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: Ufffffff.....! Have you searched the web for the solution or directly posted it???

Comment: See the Links..http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59308/sqlconnect-a-library-for-connecting-objective-c-swift-applications-to-microsof  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022651/connect-to-sql-server-via-connection-string-on-os-x

Comment: Switch the sides and look on your Question with the eyes of a person who want to answer. What do you exprect from a question that you want to answer? Read the "how to ask a Question" section and try again

Comment: I haven't any idea to do that, and I search a lot in Google.

Comment: @Luis i have posted some links so in my previous comments so why are you not going through it. and next time before asking any question first google it. ok.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can use webservices, from webservice you can send data to server. Perform operations on server and send back result from server to mobile.